# Need to use function as a field when using Unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot, stored-functions

I am able to use the unpivot function to get data from direct fields,but when i try to pass a function to the list of fields it says only simple columns are  allowed.
Basically trying to see if i can have a function as a field.

I have tried to pass the function in the unpivot columns list ,but not working.

sdb.get_code_value is a function that i wanted to use in the columns list but it says only simple columns allowed.

```
    Select inst,alias,USER_GROUP udf_id,UDF_VALUE
    from
    (
    select distinct inst,alias,USER_GROUP_CHAR20,sdb.GET_CODE_VALUE('GICS',USER_GROUP_CHAR20,'SOURCE')
    from sdb.smdh
    where inst=4
    and alias=1063
    )
    A
    UNPIVOT  INCLUDE NULLS (UDF_VALUE FOR USER_GROUP IN (USER_GROUP_CHAR20, sdb.GET_CODE_VALUE('GICS',USER_GROUP_CHAR20,'SOURCE')))
```

Need function to be used in the Unpivot.

Comment: It's helpful to tell us the actual error you get (ORA-01748?). You would need to alias the column expression (function call) in the inner query, then refer to that alias in the unpivot. The rest of your query doesn't really make sense to me though, so that probably doesn't help much. Sample data and expected results might help if you can't get it to work from there - i.e. a [mre].

Comment: Give function an alias in select list (e.g. `sdb.GET_CODE_VALUE('GICS',USER_GROUP_CHAR20,'SOURCE') as f`) and use it in unpivot clause.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs ,i am able to use your suggestion and it is working as expected.